# How to update input value state via reducers and actions without redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a problem with this piece of code. Basically, I want to update input value state with action dispatch and not with setState react method. So far i have this, and state always returns undefined. Can someone please help me, i stuck with this and i can't think of any solution that i didn't try 
This is just pieces of code relevant for this problem:

```
/* SignupForm.js */
    <InputField
       label="Name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
        floatingLabelText="Name"
        value={this.props.values[name]}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        errorText={this.state.errors.name}
    />
onChange = (event) => {
     this.props.onChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.signup.error,
    values: state.update.values

    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
   onSave: data => dispatch(registerUser(data)),
   onChange: (name, value) => dispatch(formUpdate(name, value))
  };
}
/* reducerUpdate.js */
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  values:{}

};
const reducerForm = (state = INITIAL_STATE , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
         values: Object.assign({}, state.values, {
           [action.name]: action.value
         })
       });
      }

      return state;
};
export default reducerForm;

/*actionUpdate.js */
let _formUpdateValue = (name, value, e) => {
    return {
        type: types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE,
        name, 
        value
    };
};
export function formUpdate({ name, value}) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(_formUpdateValue(name, value));
    console.log(name, value);
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you show your combine reducer function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  Here is my combined reducer:import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducerSignup from './reducerSignup';
import reducerSignin from './reducerSignin';
import reducerUpdate from './reducerUpdate';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  signup:reducerSignup,
  signin: reducerSignin,
  update: reducerUpdate
});

export default rootReducer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `formUpdate` doesn't return an action object but function which dispatches an action. To handle such case you should use `thunk` middleware (or something similar). However, in your case it's not needed at all because there's no asynchronous actions so you should use `_formUpdateValue` as your action creator (you can just remove current `formUpdate` function and rename `_formUpdateValue` to `formUpdate` and it should work).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't state.update.values be state.values.update?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    errorMessage: state.signup.error,
values: state.update.values //<- shouldn't this be state.values.update?

};
```

}

Comment: No it should not be state.values.update because here he is trying to fetch the state from the update reducer so using state.update